# If P = NP can asymmetric key exchanges still exist?

Tags: soft-question, computational-complexity, cryptography, quantum-computation

One functions are easy to compute (ie polynomial time checking) but hard to reverse. if P = NP does that mean that asymmetric key exchanges will be reduced from polynomial computation time and exponential inversion time to polynomial computation time and "worse" polynomial inversion time.

If P = BQP can there still be secure asymmetric key exchanges using quantum computers?

Comment: Secure quantum communication is possible even if $P = NP$, but you can't use RSA.

Comment: If P = BQP there a number of cryptographic algorithms that are thought to be outside BQP, such as NTRU. If P = NP, one way functions don't exist and security is impossible to prove, but if the polynomial base for SAT/Search algorithms are high enough, secure key exchanges are plausibly still practical.

Comment: If BQP = NP? Do we still have options for cryptographic one way functions?